# Bluetooth is paired but greyed out as audio device

Tags: bluetooth

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to connect my headphones via Bluetooth.  Both the phones and System Settings indicate that the pairing has succeeded.  Under System Settings/Multimedia/Audio Playback Device Preference for the Music Category, the phones show up -- but they are greyed out. How can I activate them for music output? And what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I found this elsewhere on ask-ubuntu:

> 

To enable Bluetooth audio device discovery in Pulse Audio we need to make sure we had loaded the bluetooth packages for pulseaudio (pulseaudio-module-bluetooth Install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth should be installed by default).

The module-bluetooth-discover then is responsible to add a bluetooth audio device as sink (or source in HSP/Telephony mode) to the known audio devices.

To load this module we can issue

pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover

To always load this module on startup of the pulseaudio sound server we add the following lines to our /etc/pulse/default.pa (or to our custom user-based ~/.pulse/default.pa, or ~/.config/pulse/default.pa resp., if this file exists):

#### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware

.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
.endif

And it worked for me!