# Music output doesn't always switch to connected Bluetooth device

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (actually, Kubuntu and therefore a KDE desktop). I have a pair of BT headphones (AKG Y500). I have configured the device preferences to be these headphones for video and music if they are connected. This works most of the time: pairing the headphones switches the output to them. But from time to time:

- despite being connected (as indicated in the system tray status on the PC side, and on the headphones themselves), the output switch does not happen
- despite this, the play/pause button on the headphones still control the MP3 player (which is further proof that the BT pairing happened)
- the headphones are greyed out in the audio output configuration.

Some tests:

- Disconnecting/reconnecting the headphones doesn't fix things (from the PC or from the headphones).
- Logoff/logon fixed things once, but I couldn't repeat that
- Sleep mode fixed things once, but I couldn't repeat that either
- System reboot fixed things too, but I don't want to reboot for such a small problem.

Is there some software component I can restart to fix this quickly when it happens?

PS: this is similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837688/bluetooth-is-paired-but-greyed-out-as-audio-device), but in my case it works most of the time.

PPS: tried to restart pulseaudio, but the daemon looks seriously hung, it doesn't even disappear after a `kill -9`